# Error in concating different columns from different dfs into one df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two CSV files(attached screenshots). One with Datetime column and one without Datetime column. I want to join these both dfs into one df(attached screenshot). So I tried

```
main_data = pd.concat([Group_avg, weather_avg], axis=1, join='inner')
main_data.columns = ['Avg Current(mA)', 'Avg T-in(degC)', 'T-out(degC)', 'RH-out(%)']
```

And when I printed main_data, there were only column names present without any data(as shown in screenshot).

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76ILW.png)

[CSV 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiesI.png)

[CSV 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s40Hu.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wEWM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming rows in each file correspond to each other you can merge on the index:

```
main_data = pd.merge(Group_avg, weather_avg, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

You can also specify different merge types (e.g. left, right, innner, outer). See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for documentation.

If the indexes don't correspond in the files then you will need a way of matching up the rows from each file when merging as currently it doesn't look like there's any obvious column to merge on in both files.

Also, when reading in the CSV files, remove the `index_col = 0` parameter, as this is telling pandas to use the first column in each file as the row index, which doesn't look right.